# how to FETCH POST data from REACT FORM to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

i want tp Fetch POST data into mongodb cluster from a REACT FORM ,

how to extract value of inputs by name and get them into the post method ?

because i used req.body.NAME ... but it does not work

```
class Formulaire extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

    }

    addProduct = () => {

        fetch('http://localhost:2904/addproduct' , {
            method : 'POST',

            body : JSON.stringify({
                image :req.body.image ,
                name :req.body.name,
                price : req.body.price
            }),

            headers : {
                'Content-type' : 'application/json'
            }
        })
}

    render() {
        return (

            <div className = "formualire">

                <form onSubmit = {this.addProduct}>

                    <input type="text"       name="image" /> <br/>
                    <input type="text"       name="name"  /> <br/>
                    <input type="number"     name="price" /> <br/>

                    <button type="submit">Post</button>


                </form>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should ideally be having a service which takes the post call and then loads up data in mongo service. Can you be a little more precise about the step in which you are having problem? Also, in your code snippet, each of the inputs whose value you want should be controlled component. It would be better to refer react js docs before you try to go ahead, it will help a lot.

Comment: its ok i got the solution i used import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";  to retrive inputs value instead of using req.body.inputname wich is basically wrong in Reactjs , thank you for looking after my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from 'react'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


function Formulaire(props) {

    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

    const addProduct = (data) => {

        fetch('http://localhost:2904/addproduct', {
            method: 'POST',

            body: JSON.stringify({
                image: data.image,
                name: data.name,
                price: parseInt(data.price)
            }),

            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            }

        })
            
    }

    const aa =(data) => {
        console.log(parseInt(data.price))
    }




    return (

        <div className="formualire">

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(addProduct)}>

                <input type="text" {...register('image', { required: true })} /> <br />
                <input type="text"  {...register('name', { required: true })} /> <br />
                <input type="number" {...register('price', { required: true })} /> <br />

                <input type="submit" />


            </form>

        </div>


    );
}


export default Formulaire;
```